# how to see ephemeral vs ebs backed devices from Amazon linux ami based instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

Looking at an ec2 instance, is there a command (like mount or df) that can tell which device is ephemeral and which one is ebs-backed?

Answer (score 1):

MetaData Server - 169.254.169.254

You can get these instance details from the EC2 Metadata [**http:// [MetaData Server] /latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/**]

Example :

Doing a cURL to this URL

> http:// [MetaData-Server] /latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/

Might Return

- ami
- ephemeral0
- root

You can further query

> http:// [MetaData-Server] /latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/**ephemeral0**

To get the ephemeral's info